# COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat app: file does not exist

Tags: python, django, docker

I am having an issue when I ran :

`sudo docker-compose up -d --build`

I am getting this error :

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  281.1MB
Step 1/12 : FROM python:3.9.6-alpine
 ---> 0238e48b207f
Step 2/12 : ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a03ccfedc62e
Step 3/12 : ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 77317bf71fab
Step 4/12 : COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4b6f8c9c33c8
Step 5/12 : RUN apk add libffi-dev
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 12e20c847c71
Step 6/12 : RUN apk add -u zlib-dev jpeg-dev gcc musl-dev
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 768f9b4c4f86
Step 7/12 : RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 41c9d9b5ebc9
Step 8/12 : COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fbb27974c713
Step 9/12 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 442d7cb81277
Step 10/12 : RUN mkdir /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 687beeed37e6
Step 11/12 : COPY ./app /app
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat app: file does not exist
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build : Build failed
(venv) idris@idris-G3-3579:~/Documents/workspace/moove$
```

Below is `docker-compose.yml` file :

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python3 manage.py migrate &&
             python3 manage.py run_data_exceptions &&
             python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
  celery:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
    command: celery -A app worker -l info
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - app
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

and also this is my `Dockerfile` :

```
FROM python:3.9.6-alpine

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN apk add libffi-dev
RUN apk add -u zlib-dev jpeg-dev gcc musl-dev
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
COPY ./app /app
WORKDIR /app
```

This is my folder structure :

[image]

What could be wrong ?

Comment: you don't have app folder

Comment: I thought it's imitated in docker ? so I should use `moove` ? @KarolMilewczyk

Comment: ./:/ since your dockerfile is on the same level as manage.py file

Comment: Ok, so I change everywhere to `moove` ? right

Comment: what do you mean? At the moment you are asking docker to copy everything that is inside the app folder to app folder that would be created in the image, since you don't have the app folder you are getting an error

Comment: What would be the best way of handling this, you mean this : `COPY ./moove /app`

Comment: COPY ./ /app otherwise you will just copy that one module with settings.py etc.